# Google map API (Uncaught TypeError: b.get is not a function)

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Предполагается, что мы уже имеем инициализированную карту и маркеры, хранящиеся в неком массиве.

Задача: по некоему дом-событию нужно вывести информационное окно у соответствующей метки.

Нижеприведенный код работает, но информационное окно открывается в верхнем левом углу карты без привязки к конкретному маркеру. Если же я пытаюсь передать вторым параметром соответствующий маркер, т.е. вместо infowindow.open(map); пишу **infowindow.open(map, marker);**, то получаю в консоли сообщение об ошибке **Uncaught TypeError: b.get is not a function.**

Почему так и как решить данный вопрос?

```js
$.each( markers, function( key, marker ) {
      
 if (marker.id == activeStore) { 
       
  console.log(marker);

  console.log(map);

  //Всплывашка
  var contentString = '<b>' + marker.title +'</b>' + 
   '<br>' + marker.description +
   //'<br>' + 'Адрес: ' + this.address +         
   '<br>' + 'Телефон: ' + marker.phone +
   '<br>' + 'Режим работы: ' + marker.schedule; 

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
   content: contentString
  });
          
  arrInfoWindows[arrInfoWindows.length] = infowindow;
  infowindow.open(map);

  // Центрируем и масштабируем карту
  //map.setCenter(markersBounds.getCenter(), map.fitBounds(markersBounds));
   }
             
  });
```

Comment: По какому, например, событию? События именно на маркере?

Comment: Нет, не на маркере. Onclick на произвольном элементе DOM страницы.

Comment: а как Вы маркеры добавляете? Можно, например, в какой-нибудь функции `AddMarker` добавить слушатель, который потом выведет `InfoWindow`

Comment: А как будет выглядеть Слушатель, который выводит InfoWindow по клику на элемент страницы a.show (к картам отношения не имеет вообще, просто элемент разметки)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего у вас переменная `marker` – это не объект Google Maps, для того, чтобы отобразить информационное окно рядом с маркером необходимо в метод `open` передать объект карты и маркера.